# linq performance issue

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've a semi complex LINQ query that is running very slow. I do not believe it is using sub queries. I've tried to use logging and only see one query generated. the code is similar to the following:

```
dc.defferedloadingenabled = false
dc.objecttrackingenabled = false

dataloadoptions dlo = new dataloadoptions
dlo.loadwith<MyQuestion>(q => q.lotsofresponses)
dc.LoadOptions = dlo

IQuerayable<Question> questions = dc.questions.where( q => q.ParentId == specificID).orderBy(q => q.Rank);

foreach (question in questions)
{
}
```

Need help on how to speed this up. I believe I'm using the best practices.

Below is the SQL generated. I removed the actual key and column names. The count(*) looks odd to me.

```
SELECT [t0].[QId], [t0].[SId], [t0].[Tp], [t0].[St], [t0].[OL], [t0].[Is], [t0].[Tbl], [t0].[IsL], [t0].[Priority], [t1].[ResponseId], [t1].[QId] AS [QId2], [t1].[UId], [t1].[AN], [t1].[AT], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Responses] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[QId] = [t0].[QId]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Questions] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Responses] AS [t1] ON [t1].[QuestionId] = [t0].[QuestionId]
WHERE [t0].[SurveyId] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[Priority], [t0].[QId], [t1].[ResponseId]
```

Comment: Do you have indexes where appropriate. This does not look overly complex and the only issue I can see is lots of data with no indexing where applicable.

Comment: Questions out of my head:  How slow is "very slow"?  Is this the first query for the datacontext type (incurs much dll loading costs)? "Each question has a lot of responses" means 10 thousand responses or more?  How many rows are typically fetched by the query?  How wide are the rows (sp_spaceused - KB/rowCount)?  Are these tables really views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've captured the query by logging, take it to SqlStudio and examine the execution plan.

- You should not see TableScan.  If you see this, add a primary key to the table.
- You should not see ClusteredIndexScan on the LotsOfResponses table.  If you see this, add an index on the foreign key column of the LotsOfResponses table.
- You should see ClusteredIndexSeek or IndexSeek on the Questions table.  If you don't see this, make Questions.ParentId into a Primary Key or add an index on it (whichever is most appropriate).

Also, run the query with

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON 
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

and check the messages tab for performance metrics.

Comment: I've updated with the SQL generated. It has a "count(*)" in it that looks a bit odd to me. But, I don't do a lot of SQL so I'm not sure.

Comment: The generated subquery with Count(*) is not an issue.  Responses.QuestionId should be indexed.  Questions.SurveyId should be indexed or PrimaryKey.  use "sp_help tablename" to see indexes on tablename.